# Magento enterprise how to apply user store credit to Order amount on cart page

Tags: magento, store

currently i am working on which apply customer store credit to customer current order automatically so once user reach payment page system automatically subtract total order amount with system credit ( so if user ordering 200$ things and he has $100 store credit then once user reach payment page his balance will be $100.

i want to do this programmatically. if anyone has any idea please msg. me.

Note :  i am using Magento Enterprise. i want to apply store credit programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i post this question before some days but still no replay. yesterday i found solution. here is solution. for this we need to create one controller so once user click on apply credit button then we need to update quote.

code :

```html
$balanceModel = Mage::getModel('enterprise_customerbalance/balance')
            ->setCustomerId($sessionCustomer->getCustomer()->getId())
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())
            ->loadByCustomer()->getAmount();
         if($balanceModel > 0):
            $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
            $cart->setuse_customer_balance("1");
            $cart->save();
         endif;
```

that's it done.

Thanks